# i can't print the image on R studio with shinny

Tags: shiny, rstudio

I am trying to use shinny to print the image but it doesn't work due to invalid file. Anyone plz help.

**The output :**

> Error in str(filename) :    error in evaluating the argument 'object'
>   in selecting a method for function 'str': Error: object 'filename' not
>   found

Here is the **code**

```
installed.packages("shiny")
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel(title="Omega Engineering and Design"),
sidebarLayout(position="left",
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("drawing","choose the section: ",choices=c("wall cross section","wall cross section 2"),selected = NULL)
   ),

     mainPanel(("Project Avalon"),
            imageOutput("drawing")  ))))
library(png)
library(shiny)


shinyServer(
  function(input,output,session){

 output$drawing=renderImage({

   filename=normalizePath(file.path('./images',paste('wall',input$drawing,'.png',sep='')))

   if(is.null(input$drawing))
     return(NULL)

   if(input$drawing=="wall cross section")
     return(
       list(
         scr= ("C:/Users/Darren Chu/Documents/images/images/wall1.png"),
     fileType="image/png",
         alt=paste("Wall Cross section", input$drawing)

       ))

   else if(input$drawing=="wall cross section 2")
     return(list(
       scr= ("C:/Users/Darren Chu/Documents/images/images/wall2.png"),
 fileType="image/png",
       alt=paste("Wall Cross section", input$drawing)

     ))  
 },deleteFile = F)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your calls of `list()`

```
list(
  scr= ("C:/Users/Darren Chu/Documents/images/images/wall1.png"),
  fileType="image/png",
  alt=paste("Wall Cross section", input$drawing)
  )
```

it should be `src=...` and not `scr=...`.

This core runs:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title="Omega Engineering and Design"),
  sidebarLayout(position="left",
                sidebarPanel(
                selectInput("drawing","choose the section: ",choices=c("wall cross section","wall cross section 2"),selected = NULL)
                ),
                mainPanel(("Project Avalon"),
                          imageOutput("drawing")  )))


server <- function(input,output,session){
  output$drawing=renderImage({
    filename <- normalizePath(file.path('./images',paste('wall',input$drawing,'.png',sep='')))

    if(is.null(input$drawing))
      return(NULL)

    if(input$drawing=="wall cross section")
      return(
        list(
          src=("Test.png"),
          fileType="image/png",
          alt=paste("Wall Cross section", input$drawing)

        ))

    else if(input$drawing=="wall cross section 2")
      return(list(
        src= ("Test2.png"),
        fileType="image/png",
        alt=paste("Wall Cross section", input$drawing)

      ))  
  },deleteFile = F)}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```